# Questions about hypothetical scenarios

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm new to the biology SE but I thought that I could help answering questions about my research expertise (biophysics / neuroscience).

But I`m surprised about the questions of the type:

[Can mitochondria become cancerous?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/77666/can-mitochondria-become-cancerous)

[Can GMO cause Mad Cow disease and wipe out humanity?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/77637/can-gmo-cause-mad-cow-disease-and-wipe-out-humanity)

[Is it theoretically possible to safely eliminate most viruses in the atmosphere, hence preemptively cure all the viral diseases?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/77602/is-it-theoretically-possible-to-safely-eliminate-most-viruses-in-the-atmosphere)

Should such questions be allowed?

These are similar to asking a "What if ___?" question. Are these questions not considered to be off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your question.

I'll first quickly glance over your examples;

> Can mitochondria become cancerous?

Yes, it's hypothetical, but I think it is a potentially interesting question, as it has its foundations in the coupling of cell division and distribution of these mitochondria among the two daughter cells. I think it's a good question and I actually upvoted it.

> Can GMO cause Mad Cow disease and wipe out humanity?

Heavily downvoted and closed in the meantime because *primarily opinion-based*, and I totally agree.

> Is it theoretically possible to safely eliminate most viruses in the atmosphere, hence preemptively cure all the viral diseases?

Opinion based and I closed it as such, thanks for the pointer.

So I think overall such opinion based questions should be closed, but carefully, as there might be interesting questions hidden below the post. The mitochondrion question can simply be re-phrased as

> Why do mitochondrial tumors not exist?

Or the likes and that is not a hypothetical question at all.

Comment: Good point. Maybe my opinion is biased since I usually interact in the Mathematica SE, where questions tend to be more specific and less broad.